# Проблема при расширении модели users в Django 3

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Необходимо добавить несколько полей к User, изучив материалы в яндексе на эту тему, написал свою реализацию

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    """Пользователи"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField("Почта", max_length=150)
    vk_id = models.CharField("vk_id", max_length=7)
    phone = models.CharField("Телефон", max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = "Пользователь"
        verbose_name_plural = "Пользователи"


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

При попытке создать нового пользователя(User), в админке не отображается ничего из Profile, поэтому не могу изменить информацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я пытаюсь создать новый экземпляр Profile, то мне говорится, что ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можно сделать в таком случае, чтобы я мог редактировать пользователя из админки

Comment: Логично что ничего не видите, ведь метод `__str__` возвращает у вас пустоту, вот вы пустоту и видите

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, что-то я про это забыл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как указал человек в комментариях к вопросу: в функции **str**, которая определяет, что выводится по умолчанию в админке. В моем случае **str** должна возвращать поле self.name, которое пустое.

Варианты решения:

- добавить символ, чтобы return Никогда не был пустым return f'-{self.name}'
- Переписать админку(можно в дополнение к пункту 1)
- принудительно задать значение по умолчанию и null и blank в значение False

Answer (score 1):

А когда говорится, что изучен яндекс, имеется ввиду джанго документация? Вот тут есть пример как заинлайнить [extending-the-existing-user-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Ошибка при добавлений связанна с тем что профиль с таким юзером видимо уже есть, так как связь 1 к 1 и в базе добавлено ограничение на уникальность.

*PS.*

- для отображения списка в админке не советую использовать `__str__`, лучше явно определить список полей [ModelAdmin.list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).
- предлагаю подумать насчет нужно ли вам иметь в двух местах поле `email` одновременно в Profile и User моделях

Comment: Иметь повторяющиеся поля мне все же приходится, т.к они используются не совсем "прямолинейно", но не суть, я прочитал документацию на эту тему и о стандартных полях  знаю. Про __str__... Да, я в тот же день переписал админку под себя, но __str__ все же оставил, она используется для отображения уведомления о изменениях с записью